# Can I list Azure resource groups from a local C# application?

Tags: c#, azure

I am trying to implement a feature in a local C#.NET application. The application has my AAD credentials stored in variables (username and password).

I can't seem to find any way to do what Get-AzureRMResourceGroups does in PowerShell, in C#. I have tried to use Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent without any success.

All I can find is how to access Azure resources, passing data and such - which I am not interested in. I want to list resource groups, resources and their permissions. If possible, I would like to be able to alter them, but for now I just want to list subscription related information.

Thanks, and please don't hesitate to edit this question to improve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need to use [`ResourceManagementClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.resourcemanager.resourcemanagementclient?view=azure-dotnet), something like:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager;
...
var tenantId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_TENANT_ID");
var clientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_CLIENT_ID");
var secret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SECRET");
var subscriptionId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID");

// Build the service credentials and Azure Resource Manager clients
var serviceCreds = await ApplicationTokenProvider.LoginSilentAsync(tenantId, clientId, secret);
var resourceClient = new ResourceManagementClient(serviceCreds);
resourceClient.SubscriptionId = subscriptionId;

// Getting the resource groups
var groups=resourceClient.ResourceGroups.List().ToList();
```

Comment: This is something to work with! But do I really need the TenantID and ClientID if I have a user which has access to multiple subscriptions? Not sure on how to get the AZURE_CLIENT_ID and AZURE_SECRET from my local machine? I might be stupid here, but I'll try to do my best :-)

Comment: Take a look of this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal), I think it has all you need

Comment: Looks like this worked out perfectly - thanks alot! :-)

Comment: how can i get Active Directory using subscription id

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for lead @octavioccl

I used:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent;
using Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent.Core;

var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(
    clientId: clientId,
    clientSecret: secretKey,
    tenantId: tenantId,
    environment: AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud
);

var azure = Azure
    .Configure()
    .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
    .Authenticate(credentials)
    .WithSubscription(subscriptionId: subscriptionId)
    //.WithDefaultSubscription()
    ;

var lorg = azure.ResourceGroups.List();
```

Comment: For others reading this answer you need the `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` and `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent` nuget packages.